# What is the philosophical parlance for saying: "Why (should I) care?"

Tags: ethics, terminology

What is the philosophical parlance for saying: "Why (should I) care?", in which I'll loosely define "care" as an inclination towards one action over another.
p.s. what are proper tags for this question; I am not trained in philosophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it: "Why should I prefer one action over another?" More simply, you might even just say, "What should I do?"

Many philosophers refer to the skill or faculty involved in asking and answering that question as "practical reason," and expertise at answering it as "practical wisdom." The study of such questions is simply Ethics.